# Adding a domain-based user to Squid

Tags: proxy, squid

How to add a user with the domain name example.com to Squid's default configuration file?
By default Squid is configured to only accept requests from localhost. I'd like to add one more domain to the access list. The domain is in the external network (Internet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
acl example_com srcdomain   .example.com
```

to your squid.conf. I suggest you group it with your other acls, but it doesn't matter where you put it. You then need to add

```
http_access allow example.com
```

in the http_access section. The order of http_access does matter, as it checks the access against them from top to bottom. You need to put it before the line that says:

```
http_access deny all
```

It's worth pointing out that you're allowing access based on reverse DNS lookups. Anyone can change their reverse DNS to point at this domain. It's security by obscurity. No one is likely to bother, but they could.

Comment: David: Thanks, would this be enough to process HTTPS requests?

Comment: That would depend massively on your existing http_access rules. It would appear that the standard Debian/Ubuntu config allows equal access to https and http.